# How to fix OCI runtime create failed in Docker

Tags: shell, docker

I imported a Docker image on my new Rasbian Stretch installation.
The image run good on the previous installation (Rasbian Stretch too).
The problem is : when i try to run image on the new installation with bash command (but laso with npm start, etc), i have this problem :

```
$ docker run -ti nodejs:latest bash
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:    container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I try to save again the original image to do again the import and run. But it's always the same problem.

The docker version on the previous installation is : 18.04.0-ce
And now: 18.09.0.

I try to install the same version of docker than before but it didn't change anything.

I also try this solution : https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/561
Which say to remove the line "MountFlags=slave" in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
But i don't have this file. So i did :

```
grep -sr "MountFlags=slave" /
```

Output :

```
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:MountFlags=slave
```

so, I went to /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service to put in commentary the line "MountFlags=slave".
Then I did : `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart docker`

But noting work and I have still the same problem.

Finally this works :
    docker run hello-world

My Dockerfile :

```
    FROM node:8-jessie

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y vim fswebcam 

# for mjpg_streamer
RUN apt-get install -y cmake libjpeg8-dev
RUN apt-get install -y gcc g++
EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app
CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

I don't understand why my image can't run on my new installation whereas it works on my previous installation.

Thanks you !

Answer (score -8, accepted):

i found the "solution" -> I don't know why but I just re make the image with the dockerfile.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread but putting the solution here that worked for me.

I had the same problem when importing the docker image with `docker import <dockeriamges.tar>`.

Using `docker load --input <dockeriamges.tar>` instead solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just explicitly install `bash` in your Dockerfile.
For example change this line in your Dockerfile:

> RUN apt-get install -y vim fswebcam bash

Or
Use the `sh` shell
For example change this in your run command:

> docker exec -ti nodejs:latest sh

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have the same problem with sh. And even if i install batch according to your fisrt command.

Comment: change `docker run` to `docker exec` please ;)